# Writing an HTML response in the body, entirely from server-side code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to write an HTML response and insert it into the `<body>` tag of my page, without the use of code in my ASPX file (and only using code from my ASPX.CS file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way could be to make body tag as server side

```
<body runat="server" id="bodyTag">

</body>
```

and then in .cs file. Use code something like this

```
bodyTag.InnerHtml= "My html content";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore your .ASPX completely, and use `Response.Write()` to render your HTML.

Instead / as an improvement, you can read your .ASPX content in the code-behind (read the physical .ASPX file content), then manipulate the `<body>` tag and inject whatever you want.

Comment: I was hoping the Response class would contain some kind of method for injecting the HTML into the body.

Comment: No it does not. These are the ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Response.Write("Hello " & Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString("UserName")) & "<br>")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw.aspx

this is the raw response which could contain html tags as you wish...

Answer (score 1):

you can implement a IHttpHandler instead.
use IHttpHandler you can create your own page extension like .bspx or .cspx
name it anything you like.